# Characterization of externally definable sets

Tags: model-theory

Let $\cal U$ be a saturated model of inaccessible cardinality $\kappa$. For arbitrary $\cal D\subseteq U$ denote by $\langle\cal U,D\rangle$ the expansion of $\cal U$ with a new predicate for $\cal D$. Write $e({\cal D}/A)$ for collection of subsets $\cal C\subseteq U$ such that  $\langle{\cal U,C}\rangle\equiv_A\langle{\cal U, D}\rangle$.

> **Question:** Is there some easy condition on  $e(\cal D)$ that characterizes sets that are *externally definable*?

Recall that $\cal D$ is *externally definable* if it has the form $\big\{a\ :\ \varphi(x;a)\in p\big\}$ for some global type $p\in S_x(\cal U)$ and some formula $\varphi(x;z)\in L$.

By the way of example, notice that we can easily characterize definablity. Namely, $\cal D$ is definable if and only if $e({\cal D}/A)$ is finite  (or, for that matters, $=1$ or $<\kappa$) for some $A$.

Not relevant to the question (but motivates me): it can be shown that $\cal D$ is externally definable if for some $A$ the VC-dimension of $e({\cal D}/A)$ is finite. Clearly, the converse may fail unless we assume that $T$ is nip.

Comment: The global type $p$ is a $1$-type, or do you allow $n$-types? If so, then is externally definable the same as the trace on $\mathcal U$ of a definable (with parameters) set in an elementary extension of $\mathcal U$?